# How to understand the following limits when kapa limits to Zero

Tags: stochastic-calculus, mathematics, vasicek

The equation is quite simple, however it is not very obvious to me to have the following relationship:
$$\begin{equation}
\frac{1-exp(-\kappa(T-t))}{\kappa}\rightarrow(T-t) \quad \rm{when\space} \kappa \rightarrow 0 
\end{equation}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask this question in other site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**:D** Is it a joke?
$$\underset{\kappa \to 0 }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{1-e^{-\kappa(T-t)}}{\kappa}=\underset{\kappa \to 0 }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\frac{d}{d\kappa}\left(1-e^{-\kappa(T-t)}\right)}{\frac{d}{d\kappa}\kappa}=\underset{\kappa \to 0 }{\mathop{\lim }}\,(T-t) e^{-\kappa(T-t)}=T-t$$

Comment: That is a brilliant way to do it (ofc it has to be defined for both denominator and numerator for kappa)!

Comment: Ok it is brilliant way :D :D :D

Comment: :) It's called l'Hospital rule @Donkey_JOHN, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule